# When I build x264 with android-ndk it not done

Tags: android-ndk, x264

When I build x264 with android-ndk it not done.

[image]

```
Unknown option file/x264/android/armeabi, ignored
Unknown option --target-os=android, ignored
Unknown option --enable-cross-compile, ignored
Unknown option --arch=arm, ignored
Unknown option --cpu=armv5te, ignored
Unknown option --enable-armv5te, ignored
Unknown option --disable-stripping, ignored
No working C compiler found.
Makefile:3: config.mak: No such file or directory
./configure
platform:      X86_64
byte order:    little-endian
system:        LINUX
cli:           yes
libx264:       internal
shared:        no
static:        no
asm:           yes
interlaced:    yes
avs:           avxsynth
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        posix
opencl:        yes
filters:       crop select_every
lto:           no
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no 
PIC:           no
bit depth:     all
chroma format: all
```

My build file

```
#!/bin/bash

TOOLCHAIN=/home/s/my_toolchains/arm
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
rm -f $(pwd)/compat/strtod.o
function build_one
{
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-static  --enable-pic   --target-os=android --enable-cross- compile --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot $ADDITIONAL_CONFIG_FLAG
make clean
make 
make install
}

CPU=armeabi
mkdir -p $(pwd)/android/$CPU
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm -march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float"
ADDI_LDFLAGS=""
ADDITIONAL_CONFIG_FLAG="--arch=arm --cpu=armv5te --enable-armv5te --disable-asm --disable-stripping"
build_one
```

How can I solve this?

why this is not done? I made the build file properly but this is not done?

I use ubuntu os to build this file.

It comes   Unknown option --target-os=android, ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use a deprecated version of x264, because i succeed compiled the latest version form here https://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html using the following scripts:

### armeabi-v7a

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDK=F:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle # your android ndk folder
export HOST_TAG=windows-x86_64 # adjust to your building host
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_TAG

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang # c compiler path
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang++ # c++ compiler path

function build_armeabi-v7a
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=./android/armeabi-v7a \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-asm \
  --disable-opencl \
  --disable-cli \
  --host=arm-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot \

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_armeabi-v7a
echo build_armeabi-v7a finished
```

### arm64-v8a

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDK=F:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
export HOST_TAG=windows-x86_64 # adjust to your building host
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_TAG

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang++

function build_arm64-v8a
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=./android/arm64-v8a \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-asm \
  --disable-opencl \
  --disable-cli \
  --host=aarch64-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android- \
  --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot \

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_arm64-v8a
echo build_arm64-v8a finished
```

### x86

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDK=F:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
export HOST_TAG=windows-x86_64 # adjust to your building host
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_TAG

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/i686-linux-android18-clang
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/i686-linux-android18-clang++

function build_x86
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=./android/x86 \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-asm \
  --disable-opencl \
  --disable-cli \
  --host=i686-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/i686-linux-android- \
  --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot \

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_x86
echo build_x86 finished
```

### x86_64

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDK=F:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
export HOST_TAG=windows-x86_64 # adjust to your building host
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_TAG

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android21-clang
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android21-clang++

function build_x86_64
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=./android/x86_64 \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-asm \
  --disable-opencl \
  --disable-cli \
  --host=x86_64-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android- \
  --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot \

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_x86_64
echo build_x86_64 finished
```

**And don't forget to change export variables that i described in armeabi-v7a script.**

Comment: how can I build x264 for arm64-v8a , armeabi  , x86 and x86_64?

Comment: i'll add this scripts to this answer if need, but first try to compile at least for armeabi-v7a and check will it be successfull

Comment: give script for this [arm64-v8a , armeabi , x86 and x86_64].

Comment: ok, i updated my answer, and i don't have a script for "armeabi" because my project doesn't support android versions below 5.0

Comment: I keep getting "No working C compiler found.". I am using NDK 21 download directly from  google website :(

Comment: @Michael same things is happening with me . Have you solved it yet ?

Comment: @AashitShah yeah I remember there is something wrong with the version

Comment: @Michael with the NDK version or the x264 version ?